# Firebase Realtime Database security rules regular expression: match string that does NOT contain http or https

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase Realtime Database security rules regular expression rules are slightly different from 'normal' regular expression rules.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex
So, in firebase, how can I match any string that does NOT contain http or https.  Normally, this would be very easy, but given firebase regular expression restrictions, it's NOT easy.  If anybody can figure this out, I would be very happy.  Thank you for looking.

Here's an example of a valid firebase database string:

> The lazy fox jumped over the brown cow.

The above string is valid because it does not contain http or https.

And here's an example of a NON-valid firebase database string simply because it contains http or https:

> The lazy fox http://zz.dd.aa jumped over the brown https://aaa.bb cow.

I've already checked stackoverflow posts regarding firebase database regular expression issues and non of them are like mine.

I don't have any code because I don't know the solution or how to even start.

Answer (score 3):

I am not the best Firebase rules guy but if you want to validate data being written to a node and deny any string that has http or https, try this

```
"rule_test": {
   ".validate": "newData.isString() && !newData.val().matches(/(http|https)/)"
}
```

using the simulator, this was allowed

> The lazy fox jumped over the brown cow.

and this was denied

> The lazy fox http://zz.dd.aa jumped over the brown https://aaa.bb cow.

Comment: This was amazingly simple....  and it works beautifully.  I almost gave up on using Firebase because of stuff like this.  Thank you.  You are an amazing person.